# How to make float value positive in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame, and I need to update the value in column 'difference' from minus value to plus value, if the value in column '3_min' == 0.0
I try to do the next action, but I don't know what argument I need to paste to the function abs.

```
df.loc[df['3_min'] == 0.0, 'difference'] = abs() # ????
```

Below is a screenshot of part a DataFrame, and allotted the values which I require to change
(for example, from -772.00 to 772.00 and from -213.00 to 213.00). I would be grateful for your help.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes I use this solution and you can avoid using abs () with the same result `df.loc[df['3_min']==0,'difference'] = df.loc[df['3_min']==0,'difference'].apply(lambda x: x * -1)`

Comment: @andres but why?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['3_min']==0.0, 'difference'] = df.loc[df['3_min']==0.0, 'difference'].abs()
```

*<sub>As posted by [9769953](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9769953/9769953) and [Ondro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783828/ondro) in the comments</sub>*